# Time between successive retries in Fluent Bit

Tags: linux, fluentd, fluent-bit

There is a property called **Retry_Limit** but how to set time between successive retries?

```
[OUTPUT]
  Name            es
  Host            192.168.5.20
  Port            9200
  Logstash_Format On
  Retry_Limit     5
```

Answer (score 3):

Every retry is scheduled based on a backoff+jitter algorithm to avoid congestion with multiple retries. You cannot control interval between retries.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/2.0/administration/scheduling-and-retries), two parameters `scheduler.cap` and `scheduler.base` are added since v1.8.7 (although it it not mentioned at v1.9 doc...).